# Problem with USB device on Debian

Tags: debian, usb, udev

I used to be able to plug my USB headphones in and out without an issue.  I occasionally had to use the Sound section of settings to reset the device back to my headphones, but that was it.  Today, I wasn't able to get them working and after plugging in and out a few times, they stopped appearing in the list of devices.

I ran udevadm monitor and then plugged them in to see what was happening (see below) but it looks as if the device is getting added but then immediately removed.  They are connected via a hub, but I don't think that makes a difference, other than giving us a lot more output to trawl through :-(

Any thoughts?

```
john@StudyPC:~$ udevadm monitor --udev
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [2481.852557] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0021/input/input41/mouse0 (input)
UDEV  [2481.878227] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0021/input/input41/event4 (input)
UDEV  [2481.898409] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0021/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2481.899562] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0021/input/input41 (input)
UDEV  [2481.900458] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0021 (hid)
UDEV  [2481.901559] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2481.902511] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1 (usb)
UDEV  [2481.947137] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/input42::numlock (leds)
UDEV  [2481.948422] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/input42::scrolllock (leds)
UDEV  [2481.949203] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/input42::capslock (leds)
UDEV  [2481.949904] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/input42::numlock (leds)
UDEV  [2481.950998] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/input42::compose (leds)
UDEV  [2481.951281] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/input42::kana (leds)
UDEV  [2481.952721] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/input42::capslock (leds)
UDEV  [2481.953260] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/input42::scrolllock (leds)
UDEV  [2481.953460] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/input42::kana (leds)
UDEV  [2481.961925] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42/event5 (input)
UDEV  [2481.990163] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/input/input42 (input)
UDEV  [2481.991174] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2481.992121] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0022 (hid)
UDEV  [2481.992979] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2482.026264] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.0023/input/input43/event9 (input)
UDEV  [2482.046072] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.0023/input/input43 (input)
UDEV  [2482.046600] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.0023/hidraw/hidraw2 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2482.047491] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.0023 (hid)
UDEV  [2482.048082] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [2482.049015] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3 (usb)
UDEV  [2482.049160] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2482.050147] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [2482.425829] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [2482.428596] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.891171] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.892113] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.894737] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.894789] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.896482] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.897352] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.899359] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.899659] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.901082] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2 (sound)
UDEV  [2483.901327] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.903090] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0025 (hid)
UDEV  [2483.903415] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026 (hid)
UDEV  [2483.904608] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2/pcmC2D0p (sound)
UDEV  [2483.907424] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0025/hidraw/hidraw0 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2483.908755] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2483.908937] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46 (input)
UDEV  [2483.910801] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0025/input/input45 (input)
UDEV  [2483.913480] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [2483.913591] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/input46::scrolllock (leds)
UDEV  [2483.913757] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/input46::capslock (leds)
UDEV  [2483.916214] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/input46::scrolllock (leds)
UDEV  [2483.917288] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:2000.0028 (hid)
UDEV  [2483.917803] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.0027 (hid)
UDEV  [2483.918573] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0025/input/input45/mouse0 (input)
UDEV  [2483.918611] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/input46::numlock (leds)
UDEV  [2483.921679] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:2000.0028/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2483.922774] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2/pcmC2D0c (sound)
UDEV  [2483.924691] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/input46::numlock (leds)
UDEV  [2483.924807] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:2000.0028/input/input48 (input)
UDEV  [2483.926085] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.0027/input/input47 (input)
UDEV  [2483.928405] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/input46::kana (leds)
UDEV  [2483.929192] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/input46::compose (leds)
UDEV  [2483.930449] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/input46::kana (leds)
UDEV  [2483.931191] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/input46::capslock (leds)
UDEV  [2483.931880] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.0027/hidraw/hidraw2 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2483.942090] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2/controlC2 (sound)
UDEV  [2483.944804] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2 (sound)
UDEV  [2483.971457] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.0027/input/input47/event9 (input)
UDEV  [2483.983444] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0026/input/input46/event5 (input)
UDEV  [2483.983861] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:2000.0028/input/input48/event10 (input)
UDEV  [2484.025328] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0025/input/input45/event4 (input)
UDEV  [2484.031531] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2/pcmC2D0c (sound)
UDEV  [2484.031575] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2/pcmC2D0p (sound)
UDEV  [2484.032364] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2/controlC2 (sound)
UDEV  [2484.033251] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2 (sound)
UDEV  [2484.037642] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [2484.038499] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [2484.038720] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [2484.058286] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:2000.0028/input/input48/event10 (input)
UDEV  [2484.123860] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:2000.0028/input/input48 (input)
UDEV  [2484.124213] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:2000.0028/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
UDEV  [2484.125051] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:2000.0028 (hid)
UDEV  [2484.125842] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [2484.126953] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4 (usb)
^Cjohn@StudyPC:~$
```

See below for Syslog entries from trying it this morning

```
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.315836] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 58
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.315840] usb 2-1.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 59
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) config/udev: removing device SiliconWin mouse
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "fd" "44"
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.344338] usb 2-1.3.3: USB disconnect, device number 65
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) config/udev: removing device U
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "fd" "40"
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:73
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) config/udev: removing device U
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "fd" "33"
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:74
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.724015] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 66 using uhci_hcd
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.845839] usb 2-1.3: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.867840] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0605
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.867843] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.867845] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.871923] hub 2-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
Mar  3 10:51:26 StudyPC kernel: [22005.873841] hub 2-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.172019] usb 2-1.3.1: new low-speed USB device number 67 using uhci_hcd
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.320846] usb 2-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=3821
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.320849] usb 2-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.320851] usb 2-1.3.1: Product: SiliconWin mouse
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.339419] input: SiliconWin mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0038/input/input70
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.339582] hid-generic 0003:0000:3821.0038: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [SiliconWin mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1.3.1/input0
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.424012] usb 2-1.3.3: new low-speed USB device number 68 using uhci_hcd
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.571850] usb 2-1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2a7a, idProduct=0c18
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.571853] usb 2-1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.571855] usb 2-1.3.3: Product: U
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.595397] input: U as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0039/input/input71
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.653059] hid-generic 0003:2A7A:0C18.0039: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [U] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1.3.3/input0
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.681928] input: U as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.003A/input/input72
Mar  3 10:51:27 StudyPC kernel: [22006.740209] hid-generic 0003:2A7A:0C18.003A: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [U] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1.3.3/input1
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22006.968014] usb 2-1.3.4: new full-speed USB device number 69 using uhci_hcd
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.166858] usb 2-1.3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0b0e, idProduct=2000
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.166862] usb 2-1.3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.166864] usb 2-1.3.4: Product: GN 2000 USB
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.166866] usb 2-1.3.4: Manufacturer: GN Netcom
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.178858] usb 2-1.3.4: 1:1: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x1
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.180858] usb 2-1.3.4: 1:2: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x1
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.183857] usb 2-1.3.4: 2:1: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x84
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.185857] usb 2-1.3.4: 2:2: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x84
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.187856] usb 2-1.3.4: 2:3: cannot set freq 48000 to ep 0x84
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.198858] usb 2-1.3.4: 6:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 6)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.208858] usb 2-1.3.4: 1:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 1)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.218857] usb 2-1.3.4: 1:0: cannot get min/max values for control 3 (id 1)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.228857] usb 2-1.3.4: 1:0: cannot get min/max values for control 5 (id 1)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.238857] usb 2-1.3.4: 2:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 2)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.243859] usbhid 2-1.3.4:1.3: can't add hid device: -71
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.243868] usbhid: probe of 2-1.3.4:1.3 failed with error -71
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC kernel: [22007.246859] usb 2-1.3.4: USB disconnect, device number 69
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 68: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 68 was not an MTP device
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC systemd-udevd[5343]: error opening ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.4/2-1.3.4:1.0/sound/card2/controlC2/../uevent} for writing: No such file or directory
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 67: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 67 was not an MTP device
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device SiliconWin mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device U (/dev/input/event5)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) U: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'U'
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 40 paused 0
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) U: always reports core events
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'U', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'U', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.0/0003:2A7A:0C18.0039/input/input71/event5"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "U" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'U', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'U', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device U (/dev/input/event9)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) U: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'U'
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event9 13:73 fd 43 paused 0
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) U: always reports core events
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'U', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'U', /dev/input/event9 is a keyboard
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.3/2-1.3.3:1.1/0003:2A7A:0C18.003A/input/input72/event9"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "U" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'U', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'U', /dev/input/event9 is a keyboard
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device SiliconWin mouse (/dev/input/event4)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) SiliconWin mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SiliconWin mouse'
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 44 paused 0
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) SiliconWin mouse: always reports core events
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'SiliconWin mouse', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'SiliconWin mouse', /dev/input/event4 is a pointer caps
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3.1/2-1.3.1:1.0/0003:0000:3821.0038/input/input70/event4"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SiliconWin mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) SiliconWin mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) SiliconWin mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (**) SiliconWin mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'SiliconWin mouse', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Mar  3 10:51:28 StudyPC /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[710]: (II) input device 'SiliconWin mouse', /dev/input/event4 is a pointer caps
john@StudyPC:/var/log$
```

Comment: What does appear in syslog when you connect the device?

Comment: See below - it seems very confusing in that at times the headset (the GN2000) looks as if it is being treated as a keyboard!

Comment: It looks like you might be plugging your mouse, keyboard and headphones into a USB hub, and the connection between the computer and that hub might be faulty (intermittent). Or if the hub uses an external power supply, verify that the hub is getting power.